Issues with vscode.diff Command Execution in VSCode Extension
I am developing a VSCode extension and encountering an error when executing the vscode.diff command. The error message is as follows:
Unable to open 'diffEditor': Unable to read file 'git:/Users/zzh/WorkSpace/vsixDevelop/devHelperTest/test.vue?6deb297e5e1fe8f064936202c1a31e33eb49361d' (SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 1 (line 1 column 2))

Here is the implementation of the openDiff method:
async function openDiff(
  gitService: GitService,
  fileName: string,
  initCommitHash: string,
  headCommitHash: string
) {
  const workspaceRoot = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders
    ? vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath
    : "";
  const filePath = `${workspaceRoot}/${fileName}`;
  const leftUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`git:${filePath}?${initCommitHash}`);
  const rightUri = vscode.Uri.parse(`git:${filePath}?${headCommitHash}`);
  const title = `Diff: ${fileName}`;

  await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.diff", leftUri, rightUri, title);
}

I would appreciate any insights on why this error might be occurring and how to resolve it.
Thank you!
I have confirmed that workspaceRoot and fileName are correctly defined and that the commit hashes are valid. I expected the vscode.diff command to open a diff editor comparing the specified commits of the file.
